# im writing a program and im trying to make a sort of loop where if you provided a wrong answer it sends you back to provide the right one

Tags: c, loops

Im a beginner trying writing the same program in different languages  C, python and flutter(dart).
this current one is in c.

```
printf(" what would you like as your Toppings?\n");
printf(" Choose YES(1)  or  NO(0) to select your toppings...\n");
printf(" Tomatoes ? ");
scanf("%d\n", &Tomatoes);
if (Tomatoes != 1 || 0){ printf(" Invalid choice \n");}
```

I want it to loop in a way that if you got an invalid choice it brings you back to the question but shouldn't be too bulky .please help

Comment: It should be `if (Tomatoes != 1 && Tomatoes != 0)`

Comment: To get it to loop, you have to write a loop around the code you want to repeat. Which loop types have you learned about so far?

Comment: for loop @Ken White

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a while loop. The loop will continuously run the code inside while the expression `Tomatoes != 1 && Tomatoes != 0` evaluates to true.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int Tomatoes = -1;

    printf(" what would you like as your Toppings?\n");
    printf(" Choose YES(1)  or  NO(0) to select your toppings...\n");

    while (Tomatoes != 1 && Tomatoes != 0) {
        printf(" Tomatoes ? ");
        scanf(" %d", &Tomatoes);
        if (Tomatoes != 1 && Tomatoes != 0) printf(" Invalid choice \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would try that. thanks so much